# bash script Cache warmer / Site crawler

Tags: bash, magento, caching, web-crawler

I am trying to run a site crawler that uses my sitemap.xml
I've got varnish running on magento and I would like to warm up the cache after cleaning it.

I`m using [turpentine's warm cache script](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/blob/master/util/warm-cache.sh), but for some reason it gets 0 URLs.

My xml is [here](http://easyfarm.ro/sitemap.xml)

I've researched a bit around it and I couldn't come up with a bash script that gets the url's in my xml.. unfortunately i`m no linux guru.
Can you help me with some tips / documentation links ? Any help would be much appreciated,
thank you.

Later edit :

When I run warm-cache.sh i get

```
 Getting URLs from sitemap... 
 Warming 0 URLs using 4 processes...
```

I also found a nice crawl script:

```
wget -O - easyfarm.ro/sitemap.xml | grep -E -o '<loc>.*</loc>' | sed -e 's/<loc>//g' -e 's/<\/loc>//g' | wget -i - -p -r -leve=2 --delete-after
```

However, it does not access any urls either, i get:

```
--2013-11-19 16:53:16--  http://easyfarm.ro/sitemap.xml
Resolving easyfarm.ro (easyfarm.ro)... 188.240.47.148
Connecting to easyfarm.ro (easyfarm.ro)|188.240.47.148|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/xml]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

    [ <=>                                                                                             ] 7,703       --.-K/s   in 0s

2013-11-19 16:53:17 (883 MB/s) - written to stdout [7703]
```

Comment: What happens when you run `warm-cache.sh http://easyfarm.ro/sitemap.xml` from a terminal?

Comment: The terminal outputs : Getting URLs from sitemap...
Warming 0 URLs using 4 processes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have `xpath` installed and available to the script.

More generally, make sure every command called in the script is available - `xpath`, `curl`, `sed`, `grep`, `cat`, `xargs`, `siege`, `rm`. Some of these are available by default on most systems, some again are not.

The installation procedure varies with each distribution. For example, in Ubuntu Linux you would use `apt-get install libxml-xpath-perl` to get `xpath`.

Comment: U were right, I had to install xpath and siege. The script works now, however, if I empty cache and run script, when I enter the site afterwards it still doesn't responds from cache..

Comment: That's probably a cache configuration issue... Sounds like a new question is due. ;)

Answer (score 0):

We had issues with turpentine warming so wrote our own bash script. 
It first uses wget to get a url list. 
Then it uses curl to warm however many varnish caches you're running.

https://gist.github.com/jaseclamp/27c4b74e535ddd749bbe

There's also code in there to clear mod pagespeed if you happen to be using it.
Can comment that out if not applicable.